# How to remove scrollbars from facebook?

Tags: facebook, scrollbar, fluid

I am having quite a difficult time on removing this @#$$# scrollbars from my facebook app.
I am using the fluid option.
I have searched and tried different methods, but they still there.
Kind regards.
Leo.

Here is the image:

http://pbrd.co/142TGcD

Answer (score 1):

This problem appears only on Chrome, and it is Facebook's fault.

Look at this thread : [Chrome issue: weird horizontal scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425050/chrome-issue-weird-horizontal-scrollbar)