# Chrome issue: weird horizontal scrollbar

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, scrollbar

I'm getting this weird horizontal scrollbar on my canvas app (only in Chrome).
I've tested it with a html-file containing just one word, and it still appears.
The weird thing is, that the scrollbar isn't the scrollbar of the iframe, but of the full window (http://oi44.tinypic.com/2vto86o.jpg).

I've tried changing the settings (to fluid and 760px) but that doesn't do thing.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Facebook's issue. Here is the bug report: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/182748101891780

Comment: I spent 2 hours before I realized this was a chrome only issue and found this post. Weird is right!